# Вывод списка объектов в меню из YaMapsML файла

Tags: яндекс-карты

Перехожу с GoogleMaps на карты Яндекса и что-то у меня не получается.
Может кто-то может подсказать как переделать пример в Песочнице "Вывод списка объектов карты" (пример здесь - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list), но чтобы данные об объектах загружались из YaMapsML файла. Может кто-нибудь видел рабочий пример?

Comment: Вроде получилось создать работающее меню, которое открывают балун выбранного объекта. Я не программист, код (конечно) плохой, поэтому код выкладывать здесь не буду, но вроде работает работает. Образец можно посмотреть  здесь -  https://www.visit-plus.com/ru/node/5568 и улучшить.